# Why are my list items breaking in columns?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to have the "bubbles" intact, but they aren't as you can see in the picture. I have tried `break-inside: avoid;` in all areas that are appropriate.  Pardon the media screen I'm testing it out and when it works I will apply it to a handheld tag instead of a more appropriate size.

**The Code:**

```css
ol {
  padding: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: black;
  border: .25em solid lightblue;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(170, 70, 0);
  border-radius: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  border: .25em solid lightblue;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 2em;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  height: 40em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px){
  ol {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
  }
  li {
    break-after: always;
  }
  figcaption {
    break-before: always;
  }
  div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    height: 40em;
  }
  nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(170, 70, 0);
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    border: .25em solid lightblue;
    top: 0%;
    margin: 0em;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h1 id="hOne">Peter Basolo</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="start" href="unnecessary" title="The fun part">Start the adventure!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="fb" href="unnecessary" title="My Facebook!">
        <figure>
          <img src="facebook-logo.png" alt="This should be taking you to my facebook. Awkward." width="25" height="25" />
          <figcaption>Stalk me!</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="ln" href="https://unnecessary" title="My Linkdin!">
        <figure>
          <img src="linkedin-logo.png" alt="This should be taking you to my linkedIn. Awkward." width="25" height="25" />
          <figcaption>Hire me!</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to just add display:inline-block in li tag.

```css
ol {
  padding: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
display:inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  color: black;
  border: .25em solid lightblue;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(170, 70, 0);
  border-radius: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  border: .25em solid lightblue;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 2em;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  height: 40em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px){
  ol {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
  }
  li {
    break-after: always;
  }
  figcaption {
    break-before: always;
  }
  div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    height: 40em;
  }
  nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(170, 70, 0);
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    border: .25em solid lightblue;
    top: 0%;
    margin: 0em;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h1 id="hOne">Peter Basolo</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="start" href="unnecessary" title="The fun part">Start the adventure!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="fb" href="unnecessary" title="My Facebook!">
        <figure>
          <img src="facebook-logo.png" alt="This should be taking you to my facebook. Awkward." width="25" height="25" />
          <figcaption>Stalk me!</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="ln" href="https://unnecessary" title="My Linkdin!">
        <figure>
          <img src="linkedin-logo.png" alt="This should be taking you to my linkedIn. Awkward." width="25" height="25" />
          <figcaption>Hire me!</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```